# Being redirected to IIS7 webpage

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to run my application in visual studio 2013. I have created a virtual directory and also set the start up page.
But whenever I try to debug the application, I am being redirected to my IPv4 address and I am shown the IIS 7 welcome page.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my internet LAN settings.
I am now able to debug the application.